# How to normalize mouse coordinates in OpenGL/LWJGL

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to detect if my mouse is hovering over a rectangle that I drew(with VBOs), but when I get the mouse coordinates with Mouse.getX() & Mouse.getY(), it returns the window coordinates(i.e. (480, 200)). How can I get the mouse coordinates from the range of [-1, 1]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*trivial approach*

You can do this by knowing only the viewport or if drawing in the whole window its inner size. Assuming mouse coordinates are `0,0` in the top left corner.

The following will normalize the input to `[-1, 1]`.

```
double normalizedX = -1.0 + 2.0 * (double)Mouse.getX() / window.width; 
double normalizedY = 1.0 - 2.0 * (double)Mouse.getY() / window.height;
```

You can also use a more intricate solution by creating an inverse matrix for the viewport and multiply out the mouse input vector.

Comment: Thanks so much! One problem though(which I fixed), your `normalizedY ` returns the opposite of the Y value, so I just did it to `double normalizedY = -(1.0 - 2.0 * (double) Mouse.getY() / window.height);`